# Enviar mensagem para navegador

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Preciso enviar uma mensagem como esta para o navegador:

[image: Exemplo]

Como posso fazer num site feito com C#, ASP.NET e Webforms?

Comment: Boa tarde, o aspx e c# não fazem operações no front-end, quem faz isto é o javascript. Ainda sim você pode controlar algumas situações do javascript que será entregue ao front-end. Só não entendi se é um simples `alert` que você quer ou se você quer bloquear do usuário sair da página sem confirmar, por exemplo o usuário fechar a janela por acidente e você quer que ele confirme?

Comment: Quero só enviar uma alerta mesmo, nada de eventos como sair da página, se o ASPX não faz isso por sí, tem como usar o javascript nele?

Comment: Talvez você queira um link: `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick = "alert('Olá mundo!');"/>`?

Comment: Corrigi sua pergunta para que tenha aceitação maior. Seria interessante você dar mais alguns detalhes, se usa `ScriptManager`, por exemplo, que é usado para ativar o JS na página.

Comment: Exato, muito obrigado, estou começando o C# ASP.NET etc. Muito obrigado por sua ajuda.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Será que vale eu transformar em resposta?

Comment: Eu acho que vale.

Comment: Vai com tudo que eu dou reputação

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Basicamente, é esta tradução aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Poderia ver se escrevi alguma bobagem? Não tenho experiencia com `.net`. Obrigado

Comment: @user28411 Obrigado, bons estudos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se estiver criando uma página básica ou estiver estudando o principio seria criar um link pra disparar o evento (não necessitando de ASP.NET necessariamente) em html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alert('Olá mundo!')">Clique aqui</a>
```

Você pode criar um botão simples também:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="alert('Olá mundo!');"/>
```

Note que o `asp:Button` é usado pra controlar eventos do lado servidor (que é acompanhado de um `<form>`)

Pra inserir um simples javascript em uma página html, o básico seria isto:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('Olá mundo!');
</script>
```

Também pode-se usar arquivos `.js`, como por exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
```

Em `foo.js` irá conter:

```
alert('Olá mundo!');
```

Acredito que aqui o principio seja mais a questão do "html", mas se tiver interesse (e tenho certeza de que se no futuro for querer aprender mais sobre os controles avançados do .net), recomendo que siga a dica do Cigano e leia sobre o `ScriptManager`, segue link da documentação:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

### Os principais tipos de janelas de dialogo em páginas web

- O `window.alert` ou simplesmente `alert`, é um evento que exibe uma janela de dialogo simples com um mensagem de texto (e não faz nenhuma ação mais), exemplo:

  ```js
  function meuEvento() {
      alert("Olá");
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <button onclick="meuEvento();">Clique aqui</button>
  ```
- O `window.confirm` ou simplesmente `confirm`, é um evento que exibe uma janela de dialogo com um mensagem de texto e dois botões, um pra confirmar uma ação e outro pra cancelar a ação (note que se clicar em fechar será o mesmo que clicar em cancelar), este evento retorna um valor booleano, sendo `true` se clicar em `Ok` ou `false` se clicar em `Cancel` (cancelar):

  ```js
  function meuEvento() {
      if (window.confirm("Você quer confirmar ou cancelar?")) {
          alert("Você clicou em Ok");
      } else {
          alert("Você clicou em Cancelar ou em Fechar");
      }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <button onclick="meuEvento();">Clique aqui</button>
  ```
- O `window.prompt` ou simplesmente `prompt`, é um evento que exibe uma janela de dialogo com um mensagem de texto, um campo de texto e um botão pra confirmar e outro pra cancelar. Este método retornar uma `string`, se clicar em cancelar (ou fechar) será retornado um `null` ao invés de `string`:

  ```js
  function meuEvento() {
      var resposta = window.prompt("Qual o seu nome?");

      if (resposta !== null) {
          alert("Seu nome é:" + resposta);
      } else {
          alert("Você clicou em Cancelar ou em Fechar");
      }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <button onclick="meuEvento();">Clique aqui</button>
  ```
- O evento `window.onbeforeunload` é o que faz o "efeito" da imagem que você postou, este evento espera um `return`, acaso não tenha `return` ele vai agir normalmente fechando a janela e ignorando outros eventos, ao usar `return` nele você estará adicionando uma verificação para o usuário se ele desejar sair de uma determinada página, este evento é disparado em paginações, envio de formulário, recarrega a página, quando fecha um aba ou janela, exemplo como citado pelo [CiganoMorrisonMendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2999/cigano-morrison-mendez) desta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10311375/1518921):

  ```js
  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
      var msg = "Quer mesmo sair desta página?";
      e = e || window.event;

      // Pro IE e Firefox anterior a versão 4
      if (e) {
          e.returnValue = msg;
      }

      // Para Safari e Chrome
      return msg;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <button onclick="window.location.reload();">Recarregar página</button>
  <br>
  <a href="?">Páginar</a>
  ```

Note que existem outros eventos de janelas, como popups e modais, mas o tipos de dialogos são basicamente os citados aqui, se quiser ver mais métodos usados pelo objeto `window`, você pode dar uma olhada na documentação da Mozilla:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: Complemente sua resposta [com a primeira resposta deste link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser). Você não falou do mais importante.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu não coloquei esta resposta, porque me pareceu que o AP perguntou sobre `alert` mesmo que ele tenha usado um desenho sobre o `onbeforeunload`. Note que ele comentou isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91495/enviar-mensagem-para-navegador/#comment185267_91495 - Mas se achar pertinente vou editar. Obrigado

Comment: Não é uma simples *dialog*: é a *dialog* do `unload`.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Mas foi isto o que eu disse, ele pode ter usado tal desenho do *dialog* do `beforeunload`, mas ele havia comentado que não era esta a situação. São aqueles tipos de situação que é usado algo pra ilustrar, mas o que é desejado é outra coisa. Não sei foi o que eu entendi. Mas acredito que vale a pena citar todas janelas de dialogo na resposta. Terminando minha edição... grato.

Comment: Perfeito. Exatamente isso. +1

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `onbeforeunload` do javascript, ele apresenta essa janelinha que pergunta se o usuário realmente quer sair da página.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
   e = e || window.event, msg = 'Você tem certeza que deseja sair dessa página?';
   if (e) e.returnValue = msg;
   return msg;
};
```